# Domain name alias, sitemaps.xml and robots.txt

Tags: laravel, seo, sitemap, robots.txt

I'm looking add referencing the sitemap for multiple domain name alias which is spun off logic within a Laravel framework. in my robots.txt file - but I'm not quite sure what the correct way is to do this. Sitemaps exist and are present and correct, but just unsure as to the format google expects...so really looking for SEO based answers rather than was to achieve this.

I'm thinking I can do this for `robots.txt`

i.e.,

```
Sitemap: https://www.main-domain.com/sitemap.xml

Sitemap: https://www.domain-alias1.com/sitemap.xml

Sitemap: https://www.domain-alias2.com/sitemap.xml
```

Any pro-seo tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you may want to ask on [Webmasters.SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if your question isn't about code to generate an appropriate robots.txt file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: Agree. Happy for it to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is about generating a proper `robot.txt` having multiple sitemaps, then listing them one per line with the `Sitemap:` instruction is the right way. These must be located at the same directory level as the `robot.txt` file (i.e. root level).